# Are there ways to make a Pokémon evolve prematurely?

Tags: pokemon-tabletop-united

I know that in the canon of both the original games and the anime, it is possible to force Pokémon to evolve before they reach the right level (Such as the Gyarados at the Lake of Rage).
Is it possible in PTU as well to make a Pokémon Evolve without providing the conditions that are normally needed? Such as the right level, evolution stone, or others?

Comment: Why would you do such a cruel thing? :( Let them grow up at their own pace! Also, #FreeTheTemtem.

Comment: Jokes aside, I am not an expert in the system, but I think the question can be improved by stating where you have already researched such a feature (I assume without success), like "I have read the core book and found no such a thing, but maybe there exists a mechanic for that in this other book I don't have access?", so it doesn't feel like a "read the book" question.

Comment: Is there a specific Pokémon you want this to happen to or a reason you want to cause an early evolution?

Comment: At this point, it is all purely hypothetical. It's not something I necesarily intend to do. Rather, something that just got me curious.

Comment: As for 'research done'-... Some evolved Pokémon list at what level they naturally learn moves, even for levels at which they would still be their previous evolutions. And these levels don't always match up with said previous evo's. Which implies that premature evolving might be possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### It is not possible to evolve a Pokémon early

It's impossible to prove a negative but I could find no method by which somebody could evolve a Pokémon early; in fact, the Eviolite Held Item, and the Poké Edges Underdog's Lessons and Underdog's Strength all specifically help Pokémon while also *preventing* them from Evolving.

---

#### There are three small benefits of early Evolution and one imbalancing benefit

Early Evolution would have, as far as I can tell, four benefits: Type changes, Ability changes, Mega Evolution capability, and new Moves. The first three are relatively minor things but the fourth one is problematic; the "Evolution" section on page 202 of the 1.05 rulebook states:

> [...] When Pokémon Evolve, they can immediately learn any Moves that their new form learns at a Level lower than their minimum Level for Evolution but that their previous form could not learn. For example, Snorlax could learn Yawn and Belly Drum. [...]

With early Evolution a Munchlax could Evolve into Snorlax and learn both Yawn and Belly Drum *at any level*. Similarly a Remoraid could Evolve into Octillery and learn Constrict and Octozooka *at any level*. A Doduo could Evolve into Dodrio and learn Tri Attack *at any level*.

#### Supporting evidence that early Evolution does not exist

Early Evolution would make a disparity between what Moves a Pokémon *should* know based on its Level and what Moves the Pokémon actually *does* know. We can see that such a disparity is actively avoided (that early Evolution should similarly be avoided) by looking at the Underdog's Lessons Poké Edge (page 205):

> Choose a Level-Up Move from one of the user’s Final Evolutions that it can learn at or below its current Level. [...]

This Poké Edge only allows you to learn Moves your Final Evolution knows if you are already a high enough Level. Thus a Doduo could *not* learn Tri Attack until it was already Level 25, when it would ordinarily Evolve.

---

If the GM wants to allow for early Evolution, they should consider things like new Moves that would technically be learned earlier than intended, granting low-level Pokémon powerful Moves.